# Sha1 sign Nodejs from xml

Tags: node.js, sha1

I have a method in .net which i want to get the same output from Nodejs. the code is responsible to create Sha1 signature with a private key. Here is my .net code:

```
private string GetSignature(string data)
{
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
   csp.FromXmlString(privateKey);

byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
byte[] signatureBytes = csp.SignData(inputBytes, "SHA1");
return Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
}
```

And my nodejs equivalent is:

```
  var sign = crypto.createSign('sha1');
        sign.update(data);
        sign.end();
        var signed = sign.sign(pemKey,'base64');
```

However, the result of these two are not the same. Please help me through this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written two programs, one in Node.js and another in C# to demonstrate signing with the same key and the same data, in this case "hello world".

The resulting signature is the same for both:

Node.js

```
NrBWcxfoUavH+6cG9rWRtfKKkMaiptrXvjeTlc9NG2ozu3YGBr17dphI3mZ24Khe6LsFQOpiJylg9i5eAxNR22yGDSRKM+SjsRe0pFVk58XdKCtQQs2IiNi12yPifA4AIBBPqCJSGLqTlRKx3urAkpkTAHCBTpMj2BJ95FuufIkzL90SdZYEz0QC8O9nNpatVYlmnCLdU/iAoc7D4gJIBBBzKxaCGL81tgOWf7pKKMPpkbWGH+6z1fNWnz4HDoIz+CfFwtInQP/nMhMvq5v5O3B/ndHrwYU6YwiewwOqYsvv/bMVXwOAWV5c22oFEPcdUgi6ehCwqcsRM5KtDgVf+g==
```

Dotnet:

```
NrBWcxfoUavH+6cG9rWRtfKKkMaiptrXvjeTlc9NG2ozu3YGBr17dphI3mZ24Khe6LsFQOpiJylg9i5eAxNR22yGDSRKM+SjsRe0pFVk58XdKCtQQs2IiNi12yPifA4AIBBPqCJSGLqTlRKx3urAkpkTAHCBTpMj2BJ95FuufIkzL90SdZYEz0QC8O9nNpatVYlmnCLdU/iAoc7D4gJIBBBzKxaCGL81tgOWf7pKKMPpkbWGH+6z1fNWnz4HDoIz+CfFwtInQP/nMhMvq5v5O3B/ndHrwYU6YwiewwOqYsvv/bMVXwOAWV5c22oFEPcdUgi6ehCwqcsRM5KtDgVf+g==
```

I hope this is of some assistance to you. In your case I'm wondering if there is any difference in the keys used since the code (in both languages) is very similar to what you have. In any case, if you get this example working you might be able to understand what the point of failure is in your code!

**test-signature.js**

```
function testSignature(data) {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private-key.pem', 'utf8');
    const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA1');
    sign.update(data);
    sign.end();
    const signature = sign.sign(privateKey);
    console.log("Signature:", signature.toString('base64'));
}

testSignature("hello world");
```

**private-key.pem**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        testSignature();
    }
    
    static void testSignature()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetSignature("hello world"));
    }
    
    static String getPrivateKey()
    {
        return  @"<RSAKeyValue>
        <Modulus>oTZ5Vl3o1pwH8pMNQNj47ff7WHJBjYQzGvMRstNjOWqQQnpWVjvXkquRC1xfw8l09AQxk+E3CGPmzHDxdvJFWwMIvzH//xQjvOj1LJiDiDbvMf+VQC4ntx4JgMAv5rW1DjkbpUJeRHjl9r/T17EGKtaf4srejkNRfTKxFMwWjPimCKS7IOUIKbFYQXEgbMmL9Ow6CNnE/WVD3HahC4OjznkJdkRMrmVFDC8g7nWN0jipfaWORdzgNdKByn3kYpo3irSgkwE5isdbOWe1tXImjkZgGbpn2eL8sUNpFAPwR81yjQWPuF1O/KO2Kstoc3nwpDo3L2ZGD0IWQNOJss3/mw==</Modulus>
        <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
        <P>zMnEOiaol4T6jcOIYaGhQD8Z1ZjB1uDmmizyHYQM4s1gTZDBtbqkero20c1sKFeejQ5nBZGy8eN6vBNF1Stt73xkWeED5fXxHyUn6iN4SAT/++SO7XfzFLzSLfpEWAc4i0w6Pi/tReEn3tYAJ1l2cXP2P/Sc46R2Wk3phI3hbCk=</P>
        <Q>yYcT1hTUeQ5Z9Rd9XRqygLz14VZGkKLa4IrhUKSHmHIeBeqIKXuD0ELkSgIxr679CdILVcT6/uJPqJythYriRN3UHnUx5rvTaymaOP2Eq3s2bpuXTCqipftNTu2FysmdrjT5qT/bpdRoVeoMAZDgRG7cjlJcsiExrebkZvtBRiM=</Q>
        <DP>fH9E/h02bTb4o2p15PS/9TDnYcVGQn3jc2NTpcH7m35Dx6PzP6nCCKJgZVe/Ix9xUkupMeeLpCYpHWGSGLAYW3mCAGodVpYYClkqVNtPamkvvlEK2y8K5laMaEs3dVSeeYDT/65fTxY8iOoMmd93dC2NTQBGyNXY5blr95vRqVE=</DP>
        <DQ>ECyzPt91HjI0riMwgKR/5y1DXs6Z40nu307GPr6101p1ZmwoeYvcTH7R6865Rix5Sqx9FGk26/YmBpZspuc6ueRD/h3R3377vQIdyq0uVMUS3VXHkulpHIFK9ybBMkF0UmMWFqt1aZ3eseaTCB0kotlzAklB/1oCrr51Xn6UApk=</DQ>
        <InverseQ>BdwAX1oOqMruuPiqdRPaXoydw3uSwD63/ezafG/Sqyha9m356LyP9Ys3pZQduJb8TLlpBtdO6YgoW+sDjnNhZHAL9O2mZF0ViN5Nqhmk2qNvlzLaAOr0/Gu2Mw91BG6RVvEKOpp0We0p7zAuPV02tMiLmGaoUzG5XHcMtGrXWQ8=</InverseQ>
        <D>LUbFUTJSwGNWABS4tiu5zevFlZORQZONXtZBdD3WMjvxhBojwVhRNQomVFB/PNeJlzbOTcAE2sBkA6r8xfFI9USm4jvCr/sSBm5O3VWAK3NyPlKPslTEJrOy64wOZ/dEgFgdoY5AN27U9zXs4zj+iG16vhFH7CCP9F+WSEcBVlnU+kPrAz7t1DcCYB9sckjC1p3n3Apm/FC5nyaOlhmhBHb5QSGwOQK3ICD5Ry5CCot0vN2yQmamLIq60cdy3wZyWt2j118ylMgrsJsLzdIUorBsw9NQH4v9KWGjZNBfGjhYty8M2kWClGWwBTDtQTC5wbOvTQepgyJXK50wTHel4Q==</D>
        </RSAKeyValue>";
    }
    
    private static string GetSignature(string data)
    {
        string privateKey = getPrivateKey();
    
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        csp.FromXmlString(privateKey);

        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] signatureBytes = csp.SignData(inputBytes, "SHA1");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
    }

}
```